# Running Docker containers slows down new Macbook Pro to a crawl

Tags: macos, docker

I'm having issues with Docker on a brand new Macbook Pro 2019. Whenever I'm not running any Docker containers it runs fine, everything's smooth and quick. As soon as I start my Docker containers everything slows down though, the website I'm working on loads slow as well (loading times of up to a minute or even longer are quite common. Sometimes there are no slowdowns, but even then it takes the page 5+ seconds to load, while my colleague running the same containers on Linux sees 1-2 second load times. I've reinstalled Docker a few  times and even tried different versions (including Docker Edge which apparently should fix some issues, it didn't), but nothing seems to make a difference.

I'm starting the containers either directly through PHPStorm (which runs `docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up -d --build`) or with `docker-compose up -d`

In case it's of interest, this is the `docker-compose.yml` file we're using

```
nginx:
  build: nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  links:
    - php
  volumes:
    - ../:/app

php:
  build: php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ../:/app
  working_dir: /app
```

I have noticed the `com.docker.hyperkit` using 400+% CPU in activity monitor, which could probably be a cause, but I have no idea how to reduce that CPU usage.

I have no idea where to start troubleshooting, so any help would be appreciated.

`docker-compose config` output;

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: /Users/{MyUser}/Documents/{project}/docker/nginx
    links:
    - php
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
    - 8080:80/tcp
    volumes:
    - /Users/{MyUser}/Documents/{project}:/app:rw
  php:
    build:
      context: /Users/{MyUser}/Documents/{project}/docker/php-fpm
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
    - /Users/{MyUser}/Documents/{project}:/app:rw
    working_dir: /app
version: '2.1'
```

Comment: Can you run `docker-compose config` and post the response? It could be that the behaviour is caused by the way you use your volumes. That "../" could be sending a lot of data to your docker daemon. And you do it twice... Let me know

Comment: I've added the output to the original post.

Comment: So that is not the problem. On a Mac you need to allocate more memory to the docker process. You do that in settings by clicking on the whale icon. Initially it comes with 2Gb but you should give it more than half of your available RAM.

Comment: I've changed it to 9gb (already set it to 4), webpage still loads slowly but so far I can't notice a slowdown yet. Hopefully it has at least fixed that issue.

Comment: Why do you have the extra_host declaration? This looks a bit strange to me, maybe we can find a better solution that makes it faster

Comment: That was just a leftover of some old configuration. It's now been removed but doesn't make any difference on performance.

Comment: Then can you also update the post? Maybe somebody else sees an error easier

Comment: [Host bind mounts are known to be slow on MacOS](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#performance-issues-solutions-and-roadmap); this doesn't seem likely to be your whole issue, but removing `volumes:` (and running code out of your image) can potentially help a little.

Comment: I think I read about that before, but wouldn't that mean rebuilding the image every time you update your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to somewhat fix the issue by adding `:cached` to the PHP volume in my `docker-compose.yml` file;

```
php:
  build: php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ../:/app:cached
  working_dir: /app
```

Page load times can still get to 3/5 seconds, but at least my Mac doesn't slow down anymore and it's still a massive improvement over the 10s/1m+ loadtimes I was seeing earlier.